# dynamically generated collapsible button event not firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Here is some jsfiddle tests illustrating the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/p4pbt3jw/23/

I've done more tests and the problem seems to be unique to elements specifically within the dynamically generated collapsible header.

```
var input = content.find('input');       
input.on('click', function(e) {
   alert('this works as expected'); 
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();      
});


$(document).on('click', 'input', function(e) {
    alert('this doesnt work???'); 
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();      
});
```

An easy way to confirm this wasn't working specifically on the dynamically generated collapsible, within the header:

```
$(document).on('click', '*', function(e) {
      alert('will work anywhere except in dynamically generated collapsible header!'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because the handler which does work has `stopPropagation` in it, which stops the event bubbling up to the `document`.

You have 3 solutions:

1. Add the code you need in to the current event handler which works
2. Remove the click handler that works at the moment, and move code to your delegated event handler.
3. Remove the `stopPropagation` from the first click handler.

Personally I would suggest method 2 as there will be only 1 click handler required to cover all the `input` elements which may be added to the DOM.

Comment: can you elaborate on 2 if possible? I'm not exactly clear on the implementation. thanks

Comment: I tried what you suggested but unless I misunderstand, it's still not working.

Comment: if I remove the code for the one which does work (or remove stopPropogation etc..), it still doesn't work. For now I will stick to the event handler that works and see if there is a way around it later on. the problem seems to be related to the fact its dynamically generated and it's inside the collapsible header as for any elements inside the collapsible body/content the delegated event handlers work fine there.

Comment: I will accept your answer nevertheless since it atleast gave me stuff to think about...

Answer (score 0):

The click event of the collapsible stuff in jquery.mobile-1.4.4.js looks like this (line 6854):

```
"click": function( event ) {
                this._handleExpandCollapse( !ui.heading.hasClass( "ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed" ) );
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
```

There is another `stopPropagation` which prevents your "second" event from firing. (event is attached to a parent element of the input element)

Your "first" event fires before the collapsible event, so there is no problem.

Comment: yes, that's correct and I have looked at the jquery mobile code before as well, but I don't think that solves anything here. you can see that on non-dynamically generated items, it works perfectly fine. I'm not sure how your comment is a solution here, maybe I just need more sleep :)